# Merging lines to paragraphs in vim

Tags: vim

I have following text with many lines. Consecutive lines are part of one paragraph. But lines separated by a blank line are part of separate paragraphs. Hence following text have lines for 2 paragraphs:

```
first group of lines.
first group of lines.
first group of lines.
first group of lines.
first group of lines.
first group of lines.

second group of lines. 
second group of lines. 
second group of lines. 
second group of lines. 
second group of lines. 
second group of lines.
```

I am using following code to merge consecutive lines into paragraphs:

```
%s/\n\n\@!//g
```

It results in :

```
first group of lines.first group of lines.first group of lines.first group of lines.first group of lines.first group of lines.
second group of lines. second group of lines. second group of lines. second group of lines. second group of lines. second group of lines.
```

Hence paragraphs are formed but they are not separated by a blank line. If I run my command again, these will also merge into one single paragraph. How can I modify my code to retain a blank line between newly made paragraphs, so that the output is as follows:

```
first group of lines.first group of lines.first group of lines.first group of lines.first group of lines.first group of lines.

second group of lines. second group of lines. second group of lines. second group of lines. second group of lines. second group of lines.
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
:%s/\([^\n]\)\n\([^\n]\)/\1\2/g
```

does the work.

Here you are using substitution groups. You search for a

- non new line character (printed later with \1)
- new line character (which is later omitted)
- non new line character (printed later with \2)

Comment: Some explanation of how it is working will be helpful.  Are there any situation to be careful about while using this code?

Comment: Actually the one posted by @yolenoyer seems nicer to me

Answer (score 4):

This one works (quite similar to Manuel Schmidt's answer):

```
:%s/[^\n]\zs\n\ze[^\n]//
```

Some explanations:

- What will be removed stays between `\zs` and `\ze` (a carriage return `\n`)
- `[^\n]` means: *any char but a carriage return*

So the command means: *please remove a carriage return, but only when it's between two non-carriage-return chars*

**EDIT**: An even better solution from melpomene:

```
:%s/.\zs\n\ze.//
```

Comment: You can use `.` instead of `[^\n]`.

Comment: @melpomene : '.' means anything. The why it does not remove blank line, i.e. replace "\n\nNext line" to "\nNext line"?

Comment: `.` means any char but an end-of-line (see Vim's help). So finally it's very similar to `[^\n]`.

Comment: And `g` is useful only when there are more than one match per line; it's not the case here. Please read carefully the help for more infomation, thank you

Answer (score 4):

Considering this is a vim question, here's a vim answer (as opposed to a RegEx answer).

Each block of lines is seen by vim as a paragraph, so from anywhere in the paragraph you can enter:

```
vipgJ
```

This visually selects the paragraph (`vip`) and joins all the lines without adding or removing whitespace (`gJ`).

Here's one way to create a macro which joins the current paragraph, then moves to the next one, ready to run again:

```
qqvipgJjjq
```

Now run the macro with `@q`. If you know how many times you want to run it you can prefix with that number `5@q`, or just enter a huge number to apply it to the rest of the document.

For a really cool trick, you can even write the macro to recursively call itself. It will keep calling itself until it no longer makes changes - in this case when it reaches the end of the document (make sure your `q` register is empty before beginning this, otherwise you'll apply the existing macro while writing the new one - you can clear it by just typing `qqq`):

```
qqvipgJjj@qq@q
```

Explanation:

- `qq`: begin recording a macro into register "q".
- `vipgJ`: join the current paragraph.
- `jj`: move down 2 lines to the next paragraph.
- `@q` run macro "q" (does nothing while recording, since register "q" is empty).
- `q`: stop recording the macro.
- `@q`: run the macro.

Comment: Can you count number of lines in document and use that number?

Comment: You're not operating on lines, you're operating on groups of lines, so the number of lines in the file doesn't help. And anyway, it doesn't matter - if you want to apply your changes to the entire file, you just run the recursive macro, or the simple macro with a large count like `999@q`

Answer (score 1):

Another simpler regex solution can be:

```
:%s/\n\n\zs\|\n//g
```

**Explanation:** first part \n\n just match end of each paragraph, then \zs surpass this match, then \n match the remaining single lines

Comment: Very interesting and succinct! It will be helpful to all if you can explain how it works and what each component does.

Comment: Of course yes, first part `\n\n` just match end of each paragraph, then `\zs` surpass this match, then `\n` match the remaining single lines

Comment: I have added your explanation in the your answer above since many people read answers but not comments.